# apt-get install is failing to install anything

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

I did something that I think I broke everything. `sudo apt-get install` in Ubuntu 16.xx is failing to install anything

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopenmpi-dev : Depends: libopenmpi1.10 (= 1.10.3-3ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 openmpi-bin : Depends: libopenmpi1.10 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.` Have you tried that?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Answer (score 2):

Let apt try and fix it by itself:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I have no machine right now to verify whether the former two commands work, but have found that these commands tend to resolve a lot of problems related to package installation. I've edited the answer removing them and am now only recommending the command as specified in the console output.